# How to make single selectable filter

Tags: apache-superset

I am new in Superset. I am working on World Bank's Data dashboard. How can i make "country_name" filter single selectable. Means I can only select one country at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Under country_name disable : Allow Multiple Selections

[image: As in this screenshot]